# How to get metadata when posting link to PDF on facebook?

Tags: html, facebook, pdf

So far in my research it appears that facebooks crawler doesn't support PDF files.
When sharing a link to a PDF file, no metadata is available.
This is apparent in the [Open Graph Object Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/)
Setting the metadata in the PDF file has no affect.

Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: The FB scraper only cares for meta data it gets presented via HTML meta tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution i came up with:

Insted of sharing a link to the PDF directly, i share the link of a HTML page, redirecting to the PDF file. This way you can have the [Open Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters) metatags in the header for facebooks crawler to read, and clicking on the link will serve the PDF file. You will have to specify the tags thatyou want to use.

Her is how i did it

```
<meta property="og:url" content="www.example.com/myfile.pdf?attach=0" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="This is the title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="here is the desctiption" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/img.jpg />
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=www.example.com/myfile.pdf?attach=0">
```

> ?attach=0 indicates that the PDF should be viewed in the browser.
>
> ?attach=1 indicates that the PDF should be downloaded.

To see the metadata facebook sees, check out [Open Graph Object Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/)

Comment: Its seems that facebook detects redirects via the meta refresh tags now

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work, and I'm having problem removing the cache caused by the `HTTP-EQUIV`.